# Linux with low resources

Tags: linux, distribution-choice

I have a question if anyone of you can help me.
Anyone of you know what linux consume fewest possible resources?
I have old laptop with:

1. CPU: T550(it's dual core but have some problem with bios and use just one core)
2. RAM: 2GB
3. GPU: Integration

I want to know which Linux can I put on this laptop.. Because any Linux I already know runs so slowly...

Thanks :D

Comment: any avaliable distro of your preference without (with no running) GUI.

Comment: I think [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) is the stock answer for that situation but this is primarily opinion based.